# Are Interrail passes accepted on the Little Yellow Train (Villefranche de Conflent to Latour de Carol)?

Tags: trains, sncf, interrail

As part of an Interrail trip I'm looking at potentially riding the Little Yellow train and I'm trying to understand if the Interrail pass can be used on the Little Yellow Train themselves or if I need to buy another ticket. The [Interail.eu](http://www.interrail.eu/en/trains-europe/trains-country/trains-france) site indicated that Interrail tickets can be used on SNCF services. Photos of the trains like [this](http://about-france.com/photos3/panoramic-yellow-train.jpg) one clearly shows the SNCF logo on the front of the train. [This](http://about-france.com/tourism/yellow-train-pyrenees.htm#Tickets) website also states that:

"The Little Yellow Train,is part of the French state rail network, run by the French train operator SNCF. Consequently, tickets come at standard French train rates" which would suggest that Interail passes can be used.

However, the [SNCF](https://www.ter.sncf.com/languedoc-roussillon/loisirs/ligne-touristique-train-jaune/presentation) page for the line states that:

"Caution, during the summer, discount cards are not accepted."

We would be travelling in July, is the Interrail pass considered a discount card? If the Interrail pass valid on the line alone or is a reservation needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer appears to be **yes, Interrail passes are valid on this train**, but I haven't yet found any truly explicit confirmation that this also applies in summer. [The rail.cc website](https://rail.cc/fr/interrail-en-france) says:

> Interrail est valide sur les trains suivants gérés par la SNCF (compagnie nationale): TGV, Intercités, TER ainsi que Thalys et Eurostar.

This confirms that your Interrail pass is valid on TER trains. The [French Wikipedia page for the little yellow train](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_de_Cerdagne) says that it's...

> ... exploitée par la SNCF comme partie intégrante du réseau TER Languedoc-Roussillon.

i.e. it's part of a TER line. I *think* that this fact should be enough to confirm that Interrail passes are accepted, especially since they're technically not a discount card.

There's also a [rail.cc page](https://rail.cc/en/interrail/latour-de-carol-to-barcelona) specifically mentioning this line:

> Also the route from Perpignan trough the Pyrenees (Little Yellow Train) to Barcelona is free [with Interrail].

I'd certainly expect them to mention any exceptions on that page if they existed.

There's another data point from [this 2014 TripAdvisor review of the train](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g1151735-d2216080-r197848184-Le_Train_Jaune-Villefranche_de_Conflent_Pyrenees_Orientales_Occitanie.html) which says:

> I did this as part of interrail so it was obviously good value for money for me as I didn't have to pay. I went from Villefranche-de-Conflent to Latour-de-Carol on the yellow train.

Unfortunately this reviewer was travelling in March, so it doesn't help with the "summer" aspect.